# Calculating time difference in sapui5

Tags: time, sapui5

Good day,

Disclaimer: I am very new to development.

I am developing an app and the user needs to enter a start time and end time. I then want to do a calculation to get the time taken.  Below is the code I am using but it returns "an empty string".

```
dtiStartTime = new sap.m.DateTimeInput({
id : "StartTime", placeholder:"Select Start Time", type:"Time",width:"100px"
});

dtitotalTime = new sap.m.DateTimeInput({type:"Time",value:""});

dtiStopTime = new sap.m.DateTimeInput({
id : "StopTime", placeholder:"Select Stop Time", type:"Time",width:"100px",
change: [function(oEvent){totalTime.setValue(dtiStopTime.getValue() - dtiStartTime.getValue())}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"getValue()" of DateTimeInput returns a javascript Date() object.
If you call "getTime()" of the Date object you get the time in milliseconds and can subtract them from each other. Afterwards you need to transform them into a value that you need (minutes/hours)...

```
var startDate = dtiStartTime.getValue();
var stopDate = dtiStopTime.getValue();

var differenceInMilliseconds = stopDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
```

Comment: As soon as I add the last line of code my page no longer loads at all.

Comment: @SLi That is actually not true! getValue returns the Date as a formatted string according to the given display format. If you want to get a JavaScript Date object you have to use getDateValue()

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to get the difference in seconds:

```
var start = this.byId('dateTimeStart').getDateValue();
var ende = this.byId('dateTimeEnde').getDateValue();

var diffInSeconds = (ende.getTime() - start.getTime())/1000;
```